# Need Help to adjust the numbers in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers in a column and I am trying to check if there are equalising `+` and `-` values, using both direct match (ie. `+10` to `-10`) or indirect (ie. `+10` equalling two `-5` values)

It should always check for direct matches first before going for an indirect match.

---

[image: Screenshot Of Columns]

In the above example the `5` and `-5` are matched and then no other 1-1 matches are found so we try again using indirect matches and this time `10` is matched to `-6` and `-4`. `3` matches with nothing and so isn't set to true.

---

```
ColA  ColB
20    True
10    True
-20   True
-5    True
2
-5    True
```

Here the `20` matches `-20` and then after no further 1-1 matches are found we use indirect matching to get `10` matching to `-5` and `-5`. The only number left is `2` and it has nothing to match with and so isn't set to true.

---

Can I get the VBA code to work similarly on thousands of records for both direct and indirect.

The code below works for exact matches of + and - values but not indirect matches:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
'49407
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 16777215 Then
        matchedvalue = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

        If Left(matchedvalue, 1) = "-" Then
            matchedvalue = Replace(matchedvalue, "-", "")
        Else
            matchedvalue = "-" & matchedvalue
        End If

        For K = i + 1 To lastrow
            If Sheet1.Range("A" & K).Interior.Color = 16777215 Then
                If Sheet1.Range("A" & K).Value = CLng(matchedvalue) Then
                Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 49407
                Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = "True"
                Sheet1.Range("A" & K).Interior.Color = 49407
                Sheet1.Range("B" & K).Value = "True"
                Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next K

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: First step - change `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: your example is not clear - can you include a screen shot or make the data tabular?

Comment: I need to adjust the positive value with negative value. In above example 20 is adjusted with -20 and 10 is adjusted with -5 ,-5 (-10). I need to adjust accordingly. I am able to adjust exact + and - values.

Comment: So if you had `{20,10,10,-10,-10}` how is Excel supposed to know that the two `-10` should be for the `20` or should one `-10` go to `10` and the other to second `10`.

Comment: It looks like `30` can also equal `-5`, `-15` and `-10`. Or is that not true?

Comment: Would you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58507241/edit) to include an explanation of the logic behind which values are to be utilized?  Listing a Close reason as `Unsure what you're asking` in the interim.

Comment: This looks very much like financial reconciliation. The main difference being that there is no invoice number or key to match against. In this case, you have to approach this in stages - for instance step1, match 1-1, step 2, match 1-many, step 3, match many-many. Unless you have very small datasets, doing anything beyond step 1 in VBA will result in very slow working. This kind of work is normally done in SQL.

Comment: @Scott Craner It should first exact match the positive versus negative number and if not found then should be break down and try to find the number. In your example -20 is not available hence it will match -10, -10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that will find where 1 cell matches against 1 or 2 other cells. If you need more than 2, you could nest maybe 1 more test but beyond that I'd be wanting to look at a form of recursive testing - or a SQL solution as I mentioned in my comment.

You'll notice I don't read each cell individually. This is notoriously slow, especially beyond row 1000-ish. Instead, I read the values into an array and test there. Once finished, I write the result back to the sheet. I tested this on 5000 whole numbers ranging from -500 to +500 and time taken was reduced by around 95%.

I've commented the code so you should be able to follow what I've done. Rather than colour the cells, I've used column B to decide if a cell has been used already. If you really need the colours, perhaps add conditional formatting after the 'paste'.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim vls As Variant

'find last populated cell in column A
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'copy columns A:B down to lastrow into array called VLS
vls = Sheet1.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value

'start reading from top of array (ignoring header)
For i = 2 To lastrow
    'if value is unused so far
    If vls(i, 2) <> "True" Then
        'copy value to test1
        test1 = vls(i, 1)
        'start 2nd loop, starting below value found in test1
        For k = i + 1 To lastrow
            'if this value is unused so far
            If vls(k, 2) <> "True" Then
                'copy this (2nd) value to test2
                test2 = vls(k, 1)
                'do test1 and test2 add up to zero?
                If test2 + test1 = 0 Then
                    'if yes, mark them as used
                    vls(i, 2) = "True"
                    vls(k, 2) = "True"
                    'and then quit this loop
                    Exit For
                'otherwise
                Else
                    'start a 3rd loop
                    For m = k + 1 To lastrow
                        'if this 3rd value is unused then..
                        If vls(m, 2) <> "True" Then
                            'do test1 and test2 and test3 add up to zero?
                            If vls(m, 1) + test1 + test2 = 0 Then
                                'if yes, mark them as used
                                vls(i, 2) = "True"
                                vls(k, 2) = "True"
                                vls(m, 2) = "True"
                                'set k to end to cause this and outer loop to quit
                                k = lastrow
                                'and then quit the loop
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next m
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    End If
Next i

'paste the values within VLS back to the sheet.
Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value = vls

End Sub
```

As a final note, if your cells are not whole numbers, consider adding some rounding to the `If test2 + test1 = 0 Then` etc. to allow found decimal errors.